# headlines with fancyhdr and documentclass scrreprt

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using documentclass scrrept and fancyheader headlines.

The problem is that on every page where a new chapter starts, here are no headers. Only the page no is shown in the middle of the footer. 
But I would like to have the header on each page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[isolatin]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{moreverb}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}



\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}

\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set your document margins with package `geometry` or `typearea`! And also do not set the baselinestretch explicitely, use package `setspace`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{lastpage,lipsum}
%----------------------------------------   
\usepackage[total={14cm,23cm},top=0.8cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,LO]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}
  \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
}
%---------------------------------------- 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

At the begining of a new chapter the `plain` page style is used by default. If you want headers on chapter pages also, you may have to redefine the pagestyle `plain`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[isolatin]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{lastpage,lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%----------------------------------------   
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%---------------------------------------- 
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------- 
%Redefine pagestyle {plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,LO]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}

\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
}
%---------------------------------------- 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
%---------------------------------------- 
\chapter{first}
\lipsum[1-6]
%---------------------------------------- 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using koma script, it is advisable to use `scrpage2` to design headers and footers. This gives almost all the benefits of `fancyhdr` and more flexible for use.

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totoc,plainheadsepline,plainheadtopline]{scrreprt}
%------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[isolatin]{inputenc}
%------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{lastpage,lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}%<-----here
%------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.8cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%------------------------------------------------
%% Clear all headers and footers
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadfoot
%------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
%------------------------------------------------
\cehead[\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
\cohead[\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}]{\thepage\ von \pageref{LastPage}}
\lehead[Thorsten Sohn, 1076041]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}
\lohead[Thorsten Sohn, 1076041]{Thorsten Sohn, 1076041}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{head}
\setheadtopline{2pt}
\setheadsepline{.4pt}
%------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%------------------------------------------------
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-6]
%------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please refer to `scrguien.pdf` page number 110 chapter 4 and sections 4.1 with 4.1.1 for more details.

Comment: I’m very convinced, that Thorsten is a natural German language speaker. So for him `scrguide.pdf` is the better choice. ;-) There (manual for KOMA-Script 3.10) `scrpage2` is described in chapter 5.

Comment: @ThorstenSohn: See my comment above.